# Android DownloadManager and Media Scanner

Tags: android, android-download-manager, android-mediascanner

I'm trying to get an image downloaded via DownloadManager to show up in the Gallery app, but nothing I do works. According to the documentation, I thought this code would be sufficient:

```
  public void downloadImage(String url) {
        Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(url);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        download_id = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
  }
```

But when the file downloads, it does not show up in the Gallery app. So I tried a download receiver to add it manually, like so:

```
 BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         String action = intent.getAction();
         if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
             long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
             Query query = new Query();
             query.setFilterById(downloadId);
             Cursor c = downloadManager.query(query);
             if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                 int columnIndex = c
                         .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                 if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                     String uriString = downloadManager.getUriForDownloadedFile(download_id).toString(); 
                             //c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                     Log.i("filname", uriString);
                     MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(ArticleActivity.this,
                              new String[] { uriString }, null,
                              new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                          public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) { 
                              Log.i("Media Scanner", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                              Log.i("Media Scanner", "-> uri=" + uri);
                          }
                     });
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 };
```

That doesn't work either. The URI printed with the "filename" tag is something like 'content://downloads/my_downloads/97' instead of the name of the actual file that was downloaded. In the downloads app, the filename is the same as it was on the server. The Uri logged with the "Media Scanner" tag is null.

Am I missing something simple here? I've been pulling my hair out for a few hours on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to add a download location. The following line fixes it.

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, Download_Uri.getLastPathSegment());
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer was right for me until I tested it in Android 6.0. I'm not sure if it's an undocumented change, but `downloadManager.getUriForDownloadedFile(download_id)` is always returning a URI of the type `content://downloads/my_downloads/97` for me, no matter if I set the file destination in the download request.

How I fixed it is by using the cursor from the download manager:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.setFilterById(downloadId);
Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(query);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    String filePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME));
}
```